# Memory leak with javascript settimeout

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, settimeout

Why does the code example below lead to memory leak?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="id0">String0</div>
    <div id="id1">String1</div>
    <div id="id2">String2</div>
    <div id="id3">String3</div>
    <div id="id4">String4</div>
    <div id="id5">String5</div>
    <div id="id6">String6</div>
    <div id="id7">String7</div>
    <div id="id8">String8</div>
    <div id="id9">String9</div>


    <script>

        function foo() {
            for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
                (function(i){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        var dspl = $("#id"+i).css('display') == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
                        $("#id"+i).css('display', dspl);
                    }, 50);
                })(i);
                            }

            setTimeout(function () {
                foo();
            }, 100);
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            foo();
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

I can change 100 ms to 1000, but the result is still the same (I've put 100 to get results faster).

Also, if I replace

```
...
(function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var dspl = $("#id"+i).css('display') == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
                            $("#id"+i).css('display', dspl);
                        }, 50);
 })(i);
 ...
```

with just

```
var dspl = $("#id"+i).css('display') == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
$("#id"+i).css('display', dspl);
```

it will still lead to memory leak.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: how are you saying there is memory leak

Comment: Memory usage is always increasing (in chrome task manager). I've leaved this tab for the night, and in the morning it was increased by ~600mb. And if I put more complex stuff here, than memory usage grows much more noticebly.

Comment: function foo(){ ...  setTimeout(function () { foo(); }, 100); }

Comment: Sorry... Missed the second `setTimeout()`

Comment: As a sidenote, why don't you wrap all those divs in another element and just show/hide that one? Or use a collection selector and loop over that one.

Comment: It is just for simple example. in real application each div appears in random time

Comment: Is there any improvement in the memory usage?

Comment: Memomry usage keep increasing in both solutions.